# Getting WPF ETW events using XPerf.exe

Tags: wpf, etw, xperf

I cannot figure out the correct combination of command line switches and parameters to feed to XPerf.exe to get it to load the WPF ETW provider (*Microsoft-Windows-WPF? a42c77db-874f-422e-9b44-6d89fe2bd3e5? E13B77A8-14B6-11DE-8069-001B212B5009}?*) and listen for a specific event (WClientInputMessage).

Can anyone give any insight on how this should look? The scattered fragments of documentation (including http://windowsclient.net/wpf/white-papers/event-tracing-wpf.aspx) and cryptic "xperf -help start" text appear to be a wasteland of any knowledge.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here are the steps

1. wevtutil im  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\wpf-etw.man
2. xperf -start usersession -on Microsoft-Windows-WPF
3. *[Do your stuff in WPF]*
4. xperf -stop usersession
5. xperf user.etl
6. WPF events will show as dots on a timeline - select a section of the timeline
7. Right-click and choose "Summary Table"

Here is the xperfview of the WPF ETW 
[image: Screenshot of the XPerf Summary Table]

HTH

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. I added a few extra details to your answer to clear up how to get the image you were viewing, but ultimately this was spot on.